# angular 4 - How to fix white screen after deploy

Tags: javascript, angular

I deploy my angular4 app with this command:

`ng build --progress --optimization --stats-json --verbose --build-optimizer --aot --configuration=prod`
but after that in some cases, screen got white and in the console it say:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     main.abf....js:1`
and when I look at the page source,`main.abf....js` file does not exist.I open the page in Choome Incogtino Tab and It loades correctly and the main.js file loaded is another file like this `main.222aa2da0bf59086f2ba.js`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your browser is caching the files and incognito does not load from cache.  You can try adding the "--output-hashing=all" flag to your build to cachebust your files when there are changes.  Try changing your ng build to look like this:

```
ng build --progress --optimization --stats-json --verbose --build-optimizer --aot --configuration=prod --output-hashing=all
```